# Show some text when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, html-table, show

Here I have a piece of code, I want to show the long text only when the link is clicked .

```
<script src="files/jquery.js"></script>

<center>

<table border="1" bordercolor="#999999" style="background-color:#00000" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="750">
<tr style="background-color:#00000 height: 50px; width : 250px; font-size: 25px">
<td> <center> Product </center> </td> <td> <center> Description </center> </td> <td>     <center> Price </center> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="readmore">My product name</a> </td> <td>&nbsp;This is just an introducary description <p class="more">This is a more complex description which should open only when the product name is clicked and here will be also a button to add to cart and some media .</p> <td> <center> <font size="3"> <b> $3 </b> </font> </center> </td> </tr>
</table>

</center>
```

So I don't exactly know what code I should put to have the long text be hidden and only shown when My product name link is clicked, could anyone help me doing it .

Edit : I want it to open nicely, now show up, I don't know exactly how to explain that but I think I should use jQuery to have it animated while opening^like in http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Live_Examples_of_jQuery at Example B when Slide In in clicked, the text show in a beautiful way, that what I want to long text to do .

---

After a lot of changes and tests I have made it so that the link open some text, when clicked nothing changes in address bar, and it can be reversed by clicking again, so to help other members here is the final code .

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function toggle(id)
{
var el = document.getElementById(id);
if(el.style.display == 'block')
el.style.display = 'none';
else
el.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<center>

<table border="1" bordercolor="#999999" style="background-color:#00000" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="750">
<tr style="background-color:#00000 height: 50px; width : 250px; font-size: 25px">
<td> <center> Product </center> </td> <td> <center> Description </center> </td> <td> <center> Price </center> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle('hiddentext');">My product name</a> </td> <td>&nbsp;This is just an introducary description <p class="more" id="hiddentext" style="display: none;">This is a more complex description which should open only when the product name is clicked and here will be also a button to add to cart and some media .</p> <td> <center> <font size="3"> <b> $3 </b> </font> </center> </td> </tr>
</table>

</center>
```

Now my final thing is to slide the text nicely as described in my edit so it come in a better way, so if anyone could help me doing so, it would be highly appreciated .

Comment: Start with this - http://api.jquery.com/click/ and see if you can target your readmore class.

Comment: Fixed it, now I would like to show the text in a nicxe way like what I described in my edits, also to have my text hidden again once the link is clicked again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script>
function toggle(id) {
   var el = document.getElementById(id);
   if(el.style.display == 'block')
      el.style.display = 'none';
   else
  el.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<script src="files/jquery.js"></script>

<center>
  <table border="1" bordercolor="#999999" style="background-color:#00000" cellpadding="0"        cellspacing="0" width="750">
    <tr style="background-color:#00000 height: 50px; width : 250px; font-size: 25px">
      <td> <center> Product </center> </td> <td> <center> Description </center> </td> 
      <td> <center> Price </center> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="readmore">My product name</a> </td> 
      <td> <a id="test" style="display:none">     &nbsp;This is just an introducary description <p class="more">This     is a more complex description which should open only when the product name is clicked and here     will be also a  button to add to cart and some media .</p> </a><td> <center> <font size="3">     <b> $3 </b> </font>         </center> </td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
  </center>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle('test');">Click to toggle</a>
```

something like that ^^ ? I've not tested though.

EDIT: tested it..  It works.

Comment: It didn't work and it seems far from what our friends wrote .

Comment: it's just plain javascript and probably not as elegant as the other solutions.

Comment: just made a slight tweak to the code. and tested it..  It works.

Comment: The code works ([look for yourself](http://jsbin.com/acebun/edit#html,live)), it's just that the element wasn't initially hidden. The only thing I changed in the linked sample is moving the `id` to the paragraph with the detailed description, and setting an additional `display: none;`. The reason it looks very different from other suggestions is that it's plain javascript, and not jQuery.

Comment: Should I put the javascript code before </head> or after <body> tag .

Comment: Ok, your code has just worked, now I would like you please to see my edits so you can please help me in doing do .

Comment: Could you also look how we can add e.preventDefault() so we can ignore # sign .

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".more").hide();
    $(".readmore").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default link action
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".more").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: This didn't work or I did not use it correctly, could you put in correctly in my full code, does it need jQuery library .

Comment: Sorry. I found som errors in my code. Missing `)` and `.parent()`. I have now updated the code. I have added the toggle so a click on the link will toggle the text from showing and not showing. Yes the code needs jQuery. I have tested the code on your HTML and it works for me.

Comment: Hi, anyway thanks I already have worked this out with friend that is a developer, we made it work with jQuery library though there is a simple code in my answer, now we're collaborating to do some improvements on our code so it would be final, thanks trying to help me .

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

$(function(){ 
     $(".more").hide();
     $(".readmore").click(function(){
        $(".more").show();
    });

});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` would be a good idea - jumping to the top or just adding `#` to the address bar is annoying/ugly.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/fdtdX/

```
$('.more').hide()
$('.readmore').on('click', function()
{
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.more').show();
})
```